# Track Column Values

Tags: sql

I have a table on sql server 2012 with the below info:

### Table name: Hotel

### Column name: Hampton

```
Values such as 1) Room 101/First Floor/SwimmingPool
               2) Room 201/Second Floor/Gym
               3) Room 301/Third Floor/OpenRoof
```

These values are extracted from some random table and combined by / sign.
How can I find or track where these values (Room 101, First Floor, SwimmingPool) are arriving from in the database? I don't have any access to the interface so I have to find out how the values are getting into that column.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you give us any more info? How about any SQL?

Comment: you can start with triggers, then you will be able to find user/connection properties and find initiator

Comment: I am sorry, but where do I find the triggers? What I see right now is just a table with the values when I do select statement.

Comment: you need to write your triggers to catch writes to this table

Comment: Use SQL profile while populating the data into to this table then you will comes to know how this data is getting populated.

Comment: I did right click on the table name and I see dependencies where there are two stored procs. However, I was thinking if there are any other ways to do the same thing. Triggers is a good answer. Any info on triggers will be appreciated. Any other ideas are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Sql profiler was a good one as well. Thanks.

Comment: Check this out:
http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices2008/searchalltablesallcolumns/